# Caixa de diálogo em ponto do Google Maps

Tags: java, android, maps

Tenho alguns pontos marcados em um mapa, gostaria que quando algum ponto fosse selecionado, abrisse uma caixa de diálogo com duas opções, obter informações do ponto e traçar uma rota até ele. Como poderia fazer isso?